# Read txt file data to dynamic 2d array

Tags: c++

This is in my txt file that i'm trying to put into a 2d array:

```
000010
000010
000010
000010
001110
001000
```

Sometimes the user will have more or less rows/columns of data so I got this to dynamically build the 2d array, just dont know how to get the info into it...here:

```
level_map = new int *[LEVEL_MAP_ROWS];
for(int i = 0; i < LEVEL_MAP_ROWS; i++)
{
    level_map[i] = new int [LEVEL_MAP_COLUMNS];
}
```

I'm accessing the txt file like this:

```
ifstream file ("theFile.txt");
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> level_map(height, std::vector<int>(width));` access as `level_map[y][x]`

Comment: ok, kinda found an answer, this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572962/reading-a-matrix-txt-file-and-storing-as-an-array?rq=1

Comment: yeah but how to get the width and height of the block of 1's and 0's in the txt file?

Comment: Grab a line and count the number of characters?