# reading from file into several arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, file, vector, multidimensional-array

I would like to write a c++ code that read a text file test.txt
and write the conetent into several arrays.
the file looks like:

```
[7,13,17]
[[0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

the code i have written like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  int parameter[10];
  int physical[7][7];

  const char* filename;

     filename = "src/cplex_N7.txt";

      ifstream f(filename, ios::in);
      if (!f) {
         cerr << "No such file: " << filename << endl;
         throw(1);
      }

    f >> parameter >> physical ;
  // cout  content
   return 0;
}
```

but i always got errors and wrong output, could you please help with doing this in the best way. I mean can i read the file without for loop or without handling the commas and splitters.

Comment: You are not handling the removal of all of the `[,],,` in the text

Comment: You need to read each of the numbers individually, skipping delimitters and such as you go.

Comment: You'll get more/better help if you spell out *what* errors, *what* the wrong output is and what it should be.

Comment: You have to read some books (Learning C++ by try and error is no good)

Comment: There are no builtin functions for reading entire arrays from a file in C++. You need to write your own suitable code or use a library.

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes, this is what i mean, whivh library i can use to read the content of the file directly in the variabless

Comment: @WaleedA Primary thing you need to implement is a loop. I've voted to close the question being _too broad_, because there are many many ways to to that actually.

Comment: @WaleedA Research a bit about parsing inputs. Asking for a library that does it for you is explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572962/reading-a-matrix-txt-file-and-storing-as-an-array

Comment: Possible duplicate [from "stackoverflow c++ read file matrix"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+read+file+matrix&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Since you seem to interpret some values you see: you should **always** check whether input was successful before using the values, e.g., using `if (f >> parameter >> physical) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

you cant work with strings in this way. It seems that you are learning c++ with try/error method and it's the worst way to learn a programming language.
I wrote a little sample to read a line of numbers in your format:

```
string x = "1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0";
int array[10];
for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i+=2)
    array[i / 2] = x[i] - '0';
```

numbers are at even indexes so we should iterate on even poses of the string. each of them are a char and we can obtain the int value by subtracting them from '0'.