# Reading integers from file to matrix (c++)

Tags: c++, loops, vector, fstream

So I have the following numbers in a text file (20 x 20 matrix), and I need to load them into a matrix so I can work with them:

problem11.txt

```
08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48
```

Since I know the numbers are stored as a 20 x 20 matrix, I can load them as:

```
int counter = 0;
int num_of_col = 20, num_of_row = 20, init_value = 0;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> numbers;
numbers.resize(num_of_col, std::vector<int>(num_of_row, init_value));


std::ifstream infile("problem11.txt");     // open file
int a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16, a17, a18, a19, a20;
while (infile >> a1 >> a2 >> a3 >> a4 >> a5 >> a6 >> a7 >> a8 >> a9 >> a10 >> a11 >> a12 >> a13 
    >> a14 >> a15 >> a16 >> a17 >> a18 >> a19 >> a20){

    numbers[counter][0] = a1;
    numbers[counter][1] = a2;
    numbers[counter][2] = a3;
    numbers[counter][3] = a4;
    numbers[counter][4] = a5;
    numbers[counter][5] = a6;
    numbers[counter][6] = a7;
    numbers[counter][7] = a8;
    numbers[counter][8] = a9;
    numbers[counter][9] = a10;
    numbers[counter][10] = a11;
    numbers[counter][11] = a12;
    numbers[counter][12] = a13;
    numbers[counter][13] = a14;
    numbers[counter][14] = a15;
    numbers[counter][15] = a16;
    numbers[counter][16] = a17;
    numbers[counter][17] = a18;
    numbers[counter][18] = a19;
    numbers[counter][19] = a20;
    counter++;
}
```

Though this seems very inefficient. And if I need to change the size of the matrix, I have to manually change everything. Can someone point me in a smarter or perhaps more dynamic direction?

Comment: You seem to know about `while` loops, so why not put another one inside your loop to read the columns automatically?

Comment: [reading-a-matrix-txt-file-and-storing-as-an-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572962/reading-a-matrix-txt-file-and-storing-as-an-array)

Comment: @H.DJEMAI Answers provided in this post are not similar - at least from what I can tell. I am fairly green in regard to C++.

Comment: @bgaard, did you solve the problem ? or need help ?

Comment: @H.DJEMAI yes, I ended up doing what Fanarosss proposed. I read each line as a string and then just separated the values and stored them in vectors.

Comment: fine, good job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You don't need all of those integer variables that you have declared and also used.*

`istream::getline()` is **very** useful.

1. You open the file `.txt` and name it infile.
2. Declare a `string mystr` that you are going to store your values
3. Then you use `getline(infile,mystr)`. *(`getline()` has by default as a delimiter the `\n`)*
4. Now `getline` stored in `mystr` the first line of the file.
5. At `mystr` you can now start delimiting value by value and store it to a second `mystr2` and push `mystr2` in your array.
6. If your array is an array of integers, you will have to use `stof` in c++11, or `stringstream` in c++98 to convert them from string to integer. If your array is an array of strings(char*) you can push them immediately.

**Step 5** can be achieved with 2 strategies.

***1.*** `getline()` with "space" as a delimiter ***2.*** `string::substr` and `string::erase` to cut all the parts of `mystr` that you don't need

This way is very simple-smart and does not need all those variables. It needs just two.

Answer (score 1):

```
int num_of_col = 20, num_of_row = 20, init_value = 0;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> numbers;
numbers.resize(num_of_col, std::vector<int>(num_of_row, init_value));

std::ifstream infile("problem11.txt");     // open file
for( int krow = 0; krow<num_of_row; krow++ )
{
  std::vector<int> vrow;
  for( int kcol; kcol < num_of_col; kcol++ )
  {
     int a;
     infile >> a;
     vrow.push_back( a );
  }
  numbers.push_back( row );
}
```

Comment: I have tried something like this, and the values become inaccessible to algebraic manipulation, or they are not loaded as they should be. In my end everything outputs 0. But thanks for the method, I will definitely keep it in mind.

Comment: "the values become inaccessible to algebraic manipulation"  I cannot imagine what this could mean, except that you must have a bug.  To browse some code using this approach to handling matrices with C++11, check out https://github.com/JamesBremner/tsp